# Image collection and mosaic handling in google earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to know how to handle ee.Imagecollection output for mosaic. 
I am trying to use AOI shapefile to identify the Landsat TM 5 imagery.

```js
var start= ee.Date('1987-01-01');
var end  = ee.Date('1988-01-01'); 
var collection= ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5')
    .filterBounds(fc)//fc is shapefile variable 
    // .filterBounds(city)
    .filterDate(start, end)
    .aside(print)
    .sort('CLOUD_COVER',false); 
 print ('ImageCollection', collection);
```

which results in

```js
ImageCollection LANDSAT/LT5 (6 elements)
type: ImageCollection
id: LANDSAT/LT5
version: 1502218468957000
bands: []
features: List (6 elements)
properties: Object (17 properties)
```

then I use following function to mosaic it.

```js
var customComposite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
    collection: collection,
    percentile: 10,
    cloudScoreRange: 5
});
```

The output is single mosaic image, but how I can know which images were used for mosaic and How I can run mosaic on the all 6 elements?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you misunderstand the concepts, `simpleComposite` makes a composite and not only a mosaic, for mosaicing you have `mosaic`. So,

> How I can run mosaic on the all 6 elements?

in your code you are making a **composite** of all 6 images

> how I can know which images were used for mosaic?

The only way you have is to create a band in every image that makes some reference to the image itself. But you are bounded to the data types. For example, you couldn't create a band for image ids (str). But you could think in a workaround. It depends on your data.

You have at least 2 more options for making a composite, if you have a *quality band* you can use `ImageCollection.qualityMosaic()` (in my opinion this function mistakes the concepts too) and if you are doing a more complex operation you also have *arrays*, could be something like:

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection(ID)
var arr = col.toArray()
var qb = arr.arraySlice(1, 1, 2)
var sorted = arr.arraySort(qb)
```

And so on.

Comment: The names "mosaic" and "composite" are unfortunate because both functions do both operations.  In the case of `mosaic()`, the compositing method is based on the sort order of the input collection: last pixels on top.  If the collection is sorted chronologically, `mosaic()` creates a most recent value composite.  Since the median that's built into `SimpleComposite` is applies band-wise, each band in each pixel could come from a different image.

Comment: Totally right. I didn't explain much the `mosaic` function, but that is it. At first I was thinking in just leave a comment, but the answer wasn't so far. But you can edit it or make another.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, you are correct I did misunderstood simpleComposite. // Sort by a cloud cover property, get the least cloudy image.
var image = ee.Image(collection.sort('CLOUD_COVER'));
print('Least cloudy image: ', image); gives me sorted list of images from list cloudy to higher.

Comment: I am not a moderator, but be aware of the stackexchange protocol, I think this *answer* should've been a *comment*. I will edit my answer to give you a extra pair of options.